# SFML drawing object above another object

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm writing simple game, firstly I make background image (game board) like this

```
sf::RectangleShape backgroundRec(sf::Vector2f(710, 710));
sf::Texture backgroundTexture;

if (!backgroundTexture.loadFromFile("background.png"))
    std::cout << "Couldnt load image\n";
backgroundRec.setTexture(&backgroundTexture);
```

Then I got dice, that iscreated the same way

```
sf::RectangleShape diceOne(sf::Vector2f(70, 70)); 
sf::Texture diceOneTexture;

if (!diceOneTexture.loadFromFile("dice1.png"))
        std::cout << "Couldnt load image\n";
    diceOne.setTexture(&diceOneTexture);
```

And finnaly in while loop

```
while (mainWindow.isOpen()) {       

        sf::Event evnt;
        while (mainWindow.pollEvent(evnt)) {

            if (evnt.key.code == sf::Keyboard::R) {
                diceSound.play();                           
                mainWindow.draw(diceOne);                           
                mainWindow.display();
            }           
        }                   

        mainWindow.clear();
        mainWindow.draw(backgroundRec);
        mainWindow.display();       

    }
}
```

And I have no idea how to draw diceOne above backgroundRec... Iv tried to put drawing background in other places (at the beggining of while loop, before it, inside if loop) but nothing seems to work. When I press this R, this dice image sometimes shows up for brief moment and disappears, how do I make it permanent of top of background?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're `clear`ing the window, you need to draw your dice **every** frame. The draw call should happen after `clear` and after `backgroundRec`:

```
bool drawDice = false;

while(mainWindow.isOpen())
{
    sf::Event evnt;
    while(mainWindow.pollEvent(evnt))
    {
        if(evnt.key.code == sf::Keyboard::R)
        {
            diceSound.play();
            drawDice = true;
        }
    }

    mainWindow.clear();
    mainWindow.draw(backgroundRec);

    if(drawDice)
    {
        mainWindow.draw(diceOne);
    }

    mainWindow.display();
}
```

In order to start drawing the dice only after `R` has been pressed, you can use a boolean flag like `drawDice` above.